# Getting a UIView's visible rectangle

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a custom `UIView`. Inside the custom `UIView`, I'd like to know the rectangle in which it's visible (i.e. not clipped).

The quick-n-dirty solution is to have the custom UIView assume that the parent is a `UIScrollView` and get the content size through it, but I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't involve make such assumptions.

Answer (score 18):

This should do the trick

```
CGRect visibleRect = CGRectIntersection(self.frame, superview.bounds);
```

Use that in the UIView and it should get you the rectangle (if any) that represents the visible section of that view in it's superview (The UIScrollView). I'm assuming here that there is no view between them in the hierarchy, but if there is, fiddling the code should be trivial.

Hope I could help!

Comment: Shouldn't this be `superview.bounds` since the superview's frame is in it's superview's coordinate space?

Comment: @Awesome-o: You are correct. My original code assumed that the superview filled the whole screen (0, 0 origin) but bounds would be safer to use in case it's not. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you would give more info on what is that you are trying to accomplish.

If you want to know the size of the super view you can do this:

```
CGRect superFrame = [self superview].frame;
```

Comment: No that won't work. What I'm looking for is the visible rect of the view, not the entire view's frame rect. For example, if a part of UIView A overlaps with another UIView B, what's the visible area of UIView A that is visible to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
extension UIView {
    var visibleRect: CGRect? {
        guard let superview = superview else { return nil }
        return frame.intersection(superview.bounds)
    }
}
```