# Get the tableview's visible rect

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios8

I have a tableview and I want to add as a subview a grey view with another view in order to imitate a pop-up. The problem is that the grey view doesn't cover the whole tv and the subview where I have my buttons isn't all visible if the bottom of tv is displayed.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)orderButtonAction:(id)sender {

  _grayView = [[UIView alloc]init];
  _grayView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
  _grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
  _grayView.hidden = NO;
  _profileOrderView.hidden = NO;
  _tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

  _orderButtonOutlet.hidden = YES;
   _profileOrderView.center = self.view.center;
  [_grayView addSubview:_profileOrderView];
  [_tableView addSubview:_grayView];

}
```

Is there a way to get the visible rect of tv and insert my grey view there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a UIView's visible rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373112/getting-a-uiviews-visible-rectangle)

Comment: Thanks @iosDev82 , that doesn't solve my problem at all.

Comment: You want this `grayView` to be above the `tableView`, right? Try to add as a subview of the `tableView.parent` (it will be `self.view`) and then do `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_grayView]`?

Comment: If you want the `greyView` to cover the entire `UITableView`, you should set the frame of greyView as `[greyView setFrame:tableView.bounds]`. If you want it to only cover the area of tableView shown, you should use the `CGRectIntersection(self.frame, superview.bounds);`. 
So which one is it that you're looking for?

Comment: It worked. Can you edit this in answer in order to accept it ?

Comment: @iosDev82 both answers worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the greyView to cover the entire UITableView, you should set the frame of greyView as 
`[greyView setFrame:tableView.bounds]`.

If you want it to only cover the area of tableView shown, you should use the `CGRectIntersection(self.frame, superview.bounds);` and set it as the frame.